# Error when running asp.net MVC application under IIS7 that works when run locally 

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment, http-status-code-404, ext.net

I am trying to modify the Ext.net Mvc sample in this link

[http://mvc.ext.net/Account/Login/?ReturnUrl=%2f](http://mvc.ext.net/Account/Login/?ReturnUrl=/)

The project is working perfectly when run locally in Visual Studio 2010 but when I deploy it on an IIS 7 server, after I login to the application I get the following error:

[image]

Can you help me please thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please confirm your Global.asax.cs is correctly configured.

http://code.google.com/p/extnet-mvc/source/browse/trunk/Ext.Net.MVC.Demo/Global.asax.cs

The 404 error appears be thrown because /Account/Login/ does not exist. Can you confirm your AccountController includes a "Login" handler?

Hope this helps.